# Is there any way in Kotlin to add a custom function to a property inside an interface?

Tags: kotlin, interface

Ultimately what I would like to do is have a class with a field inside of it that I can call a function on.  I have tried extensions functions but that only extends the class definition that the field is defined as. I tried to do it in an interface but ended up with a standard function call.

so,

```
private interface Geometric{


    var position: Float3
        get() { return position }
        set(value) {
            this.dirty = true
            this.position = value
        }

    fun TransformationMatrix() =
        floatArrayOf(1f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
                     0f, 1f, 0f, 0f,
                     0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
                     this.position.x, this.position.y, this.position.z, 1f)
```

which allows me to do

```
  val translationMatrix = myobject.TransformationMatrix()
```

but what I really want to do is

```
  val translationMatrix = myobject.position.toTransformationMatrix()
```

I know I could write a class called position that inherits from float3 but my object class is really the only class that will be using it

```
data class Object(val objectName: String, val meshName : String,
              override var position : Float3 = Float3(0f,0f,0f),
              override var rotation: Quaternion = Quaternion(0f,0f,0f, 1f),
              override var scale: Float3 = Float3(1f,1f,1f)
) : Geometric, OpenGLObject, GameObject/*Color*/
```

As you can see I wrote a special class for Quaternion because it has a secondary constructor that takes Euler angles otherwise I would also want this to just be a Float4 with a function on rotation that returns the float4 backing field as a rotation matrix.

basically, the idea here is to keep the data class as light as possible and then just ask for the data it holds in the formate I need.  position.toMatrix4(), rotation.toMatrix(), ext.

Is there a way I can use objects or some other cool Kotlin things to achieve this?

Comment: why not just create extension function `toTransformationMatrix` for `Float3`?

Comment: Because it will add that function for all float3s but that doesn't really make sense for a scale float3.  another reason is you have to make the extension function publicly available to other classes thus all of there float3s now have that functionality

Comment: If you don't want the class to usually have this function, then in my opinion, your first way of doing it is best. Otherwise, you have what's called the train wreck anti-pattern. From a math perspective, `Float3.toTransformMatrix` is ambiguous because it's assuming the vector is always a position, and not a rotation, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are in luck. there is a new experimental Future in kotlin called `inline class` which I think is exactly what you need.
`inline class` is used as a wrapper around a type!

```
inline class Position(val pos: Float3 ) {

    fun transformationMatrix() = ... 
}
```

and you can use it like

```
val pos = Position(f3)
pos.transformationMatrix()
```

and you don't need to worry about not reusing it or any overheads because in runtime variable `pos` converts to only `f3` and its type would be `Float3` and there will be no sign of the class.

and please don't start your function names with uppercase letters!!

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely closer than anything else I've seen.  The only issue I have is that since inline has to be attached to a top-level class it forces me to expose these classes to the user.  I tried to make them private but then the data class can't use them in its constructor since the user would have no idea what they are. I guess this isn't the worst thing but what I really want is custom getter's and setter's that allow me access to the backing field and allow me to send or receive any built-in or custom type.  This way the user won't be exposed to unnecessary classes.

Comment: and for the other as long as your consistent across a project I don't think it really matters what style guide you conform to.

Comment: Which I just realized I'm not in my post. :)